# Facebook SDK on Android - retrieve statuses

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am tryin gto access a users statuses from the android sdk. I have used pagination but when i am running the app I only get some results until a fixed date. I have also tried to set a timestamp to retrieve tha statuses to no avail.

The code I am using is the one below.

```
public void downloadStatuses(final int _since){
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if( session != null ){

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        //params.putInt("since", _since);
        //params.putInt("limit", 1000);
        params.putString("fields","from,id,message,updated_time,place");

        Request request = new Request(
                session,
                Facebook.STATUS_PATH,
                params,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {                        
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        parseStatuses(response);
                        iterateStatuses(response);
                    }
                }
        );

        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);



    }
}

public void parseStatuses(Response _response){
    if( _response.getGraphObject() != null ) {
        try {

            JSONArray data = _response.getGraphObject()
                    .getInnerJSONObject()
                    .getJSONArray("data");


            int len = data.length();
            for(int i=0 ; i < len ; i++){                                       
                StatusWrapper status = new StatusWrapper(data.getJSONObject(i));
                Log.v("Status", status.updatedTime);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.v("JSONException ", e.toString());
        }
    }
}

public void iterateStatuses(Response _response){        
    Request next = _response.getRequestForPagedResults(Response.PagingDirection.NEXT);
    if(next != null){
        next.setCallback(
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        parseStatuses(response);
                        iterateStatuses(response);
                    }
                });

        Request.executeBatchAsync(next);
    }

}
```

The code works (?) as follows: first it creates a new request to retrieve the first 25 items and issues the request from downloadStatuses(). When this function completes, it's an asynchronous call to facebook, first I parse the statuses to get my job done with parseStatuses and the I try to move to the next page of results using iterateStatuses.

IterateStatuses gets the requestForPagingResults and tries to get the next set of results. The thing is that after four calls of iterateStatuses the requestForPagingResults returns null but I know there are more statuses than that on my wall.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Could you be more specific about why your code is failing? What behavior are you seeing? Errors? Unexpected behavior? What debugging methods have you tried already and what did you find?

Comment: I get no errors whatsover. The only thing I get is in the iterateStatus function the _response.getRequestForPagedResults to be null after the fourth call...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your question is about the pagination. The 3.0 SDK has a really nice method of using pagination but it's more useful for endless scrolling in lists.

If you call `response.getRequestForPagedResults(direction)`, it'll give you a new request object you can call to get the next page. For your application, you'd have to do multiple requests for sure, but it can fire them off one after the other. Once the next page request is null, you've reached the end.

Comment: I want to list Facebook friends using pagination.Can you help me to implement pagination ?

Comment: Use "<user_id>/friends" to get a user's friends. Depending on the number of friends, there could be a paged request available and you get using the same method I described above.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out on my code... but when I run the snippet above I only get 100 results not my entire history...